# Difference between create_autospec and MagicMock(spec)

Tags: python, pytest, magicmock, pytest-asyncio

I'm trying to understand the difference in approaches for mocking.
For example, I have a class that I can't initialize because it depends on another service.

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, some_service):
        self.some_service = some_service

    async def some_method(self, x, y):
        return x + y
```

And I have a function that uses this class

```
async def some_function(some_class: SomeClass, a, b):
    return a * b + await some_class.some_method(a, b)
```

I want to test the function some_function.

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_some_function_with_create_autospec():
    autospec_mock = create_autospec(SomeClass)
    autospec_mock.some_method = AsyncMock(return_value=10)
    result = await some_function(autospec_mock, 2, 3)
    assert result == 16
    autospec_mock.some_method.assert_awaited_once_with(2, 3)
```

But I can do everything the same using MagicMock

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_some_function_with_magic_mock():
    autospec_mock = MagicMock(spec=SomeClass)
    autospec_mock.some_method = AsyncMock(return_value=10)
    result = await some_function(autospec_mock, 2, 3)
    assert result == 16
    autospec_mock.some_method.assert_awaited_once_with(2, 3)
```

what is the difference and which should I use?

I read the documentation but still don't understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between mock.MagicMock(spec=SomeClass) and mock.create\_autospec(SomeClass)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528693/whats-the-difference-between-mock-magicmockspec-someclass-and-mock-create-aut)